# Automapper 8 - An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator

Tags: automapper, automapper-8

Automapper version 8.0.0 removed `ResolveUsing` extension method from `IMappingExpression` and consolidated it with `MapFrom` extension method. However, after replacing `ResolveUsing` with `MapFrom` method, certain configurations throw exception.

Original `ResolveUsing`:

```
CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Customer,
        opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src?.Customer ?? new Customer())
    );
```

Replaced with `MapFrom`:

```
CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Customer,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src?.Customer ?? new Customer())
    );
```

This produces compilation error:

> Error CS8072
>
> Automapper
>
> An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator.

Comment: Why is this configuration even necessary? This looks like the default behavior of mapping.

Comment: It is simplified example, to emphasize `Error CS8027` when using `null propagation operator`. Real situation mapping configuration is more complex.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

New `Func`-based overloads in Automapper 8.0.0 accept more parameters compared to old/removed `ResolveUsing` overloads.

Instead of using lambda expression with single input parameter `opt.MapFrom(src => ...)` when replacing `ResolveUsing`, overload with 2 parameters should be used `opt.MapFrom((src, dest) => ...)`.

`MapFrom` expression becomes:

```
opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest) => src?.Customer ?? new Customer())
```

Full example:

```
CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Customer,
        opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest) => src?.Customer ?? new Customer())
    );
```

Comment: There is a built in feature for this, NullSubstitute.

Comment: Why the nonoverload methos won't compile?  And how come the second overload resolves this?

Comment: @RoyiNamir It's mentioned in the answer already. Old method uses `Func` input parameter. New method uses lambda expression as the input parameter. Although they are mostly similar, there are different constraints in the compiler, like Error CS8072. The overload uses `Func`, so it's  fully compatible with the old method.