# Automapper - an expression tree lambda cannot contain a null propagating operator

Tags: automapper

I have a following mapping in `Automapper`

```
.ForMember(d => d.Comment1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Comments?.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "COMMENT1")?.Text))
```

But I am able to figure a way around the error

> an expression tree lambda cannot contain a null propagating operator

Is there a simple way for doing this?

Comment: That null check is built in with AM, just remove it.

Comment: Oh, I see - Thanks  so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automapper 8 - An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54036296/automapper-8-an-expression-tree-lambda-may-not-contain-a-null-propagating-oper)